Flickering problem on a curve
Hello everyone,my project is to animate a growth of branches on a trunk, and other branches on the firsts, and so on...
To do so, in order to offset branches with the seem radius that the trunk have at the point where the branch is getting out I have made this blend: 

It seems to working fine but it flicker because of the Resample Curve node at the end in the group ‘Branches’.

In order to correct it the idea was to use a non-transformed branches group then with a Compare node on Not Equal to eliminate the points of the spline according to a transformed branches group.
But I just can reduce the number of points according the first transformed branch, and of course I can’t understand why…


This is the second blend:
Thanks for your help...

Hello robin, you are perfectly right, I edit my post immediately...

Fred I R .. Thanks! :)

Hello everyone, of course asking a question make the answer come, so I resolve my little flickering problem by using  tow Trim Curve, so simple…



Sorry for the time you spent on this problem, thanks a lot.
